# Get prepared statements list in mysql

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-workbench

As [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) document says prepared statements are server side statements like functions or procedures (correct me if I'm wrong).

But I have some trouble finding defined prepared statement on my database. I'm currently working with `MySQL Workbench` and in the left side pane I can see all my procedures and functions and I can't see any of defined prepared statements here.

So is there any query which I can use to get their names?

Comment: *A prepared statement is specific to the session in which it was created. If you terminate a session without deallocating a previously prepared statement, the server deallocates it automatically*

Comment: @juergen I see, I must missed that point, thank you. I wished you make this comment as answer so I could mark it.

Comment: @juergend as you said they are specific to the session, so at this point there are no way to get their names on current sesion? I mean before terminating session.

Comment: A prepared statement does not have a name.

Comment: really? so what is this? `prepare s from 'call p()'; execute s`. `s` isn't the name of this prepared statement example?

Comment: That is the name of the variable the procedure is stored in.

Comment: I think I got this now, thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc says

> A prepared statement is specific to the session in which it was created. If you terminate a session without deallocating a previously prepared statement, the server deallocates it automatically.

So Prepared Statements get deleted automtically after the session ends. Besides, a Prepared Statement does not have a name It is just a query string.